# Trainer in a web conference able to see what participants are browsing?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cookies, conferencing

**Background**: While listening to a training session via the bigbluebutton conference web-tool I was googling something and browsing on a webpage. Actually I was using chrome for listening to the conference and browsing in firefox (not a private tab). I am not 100% sure, but I was surprised when I suddenly noticed that the person giving the training was adapting/anticipating to what I was browsing. It could be random, but I am pretty sure it was not. It was quite specfic and the trainer was shortly commenting on it.

Therefore my question is **if it is possible that during a web-conference the trainer can see what the participants are browsing**? For example via cookies?

Furthermore my subquestion would be, if that is also possible if it is on another software/app, so like using chrome for the conference and accepting the cookies there and browsing in firefox?

I am not interested in the data privacy side of this. Just the technical aspect if it would be possible and how likely it is. I am not talking about NSA/CIA possibilities, but an IT consultant giving the training, so with somehow a technical knowledge.

EDIT: I was not sharing my screen or anything like this.

EDIT2: I was also not looking aside and then the trainer noticed it and maybe he guessed it. And it was not connected to what the person was talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably had a trainer that was very good at reading faces.

Student screen-share  was requested on Github in the feature
request of
[Screenshare from student side #8445](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/issues/8445).

The answer there was:

> You can do this now if you make the student presenter and then invite
> them to share their screen. See tutorial video for
> Moderator/Presenter: https://bigbluebutton.org/html5/.
>
> Note that the student must initiate the screen sharing and give their
> browser permission to share their screen.
> **This isn't something that the instructor can initiate**.